# Who do I format my docstring so ipython tab completion recognizes it?

Tags: python, ipython

I have a python function, say g, that accpepts a few arguments, say (x, y, z):

```
def g(x, y, z):
   pass
```

Additionally, I have a function f that accepts **kwargs and calls g, passing it with kwargs, implicitly expecting to be called with x, y, z:

```
def f(**kwargs):
    return g(**kwargs)
```

The idea is to allow future arguments to be added to "g" without the need to modify f's code.

The question is whethere there any way, be it docstring or whatever, for ipython to be a able to find those arguments when performing tab completion for f's arguments, that is when pressing tab after opening a paren after f:

```
f(<tab>
```

Comment: It looks like you want to decorate 'g'. So I would use a decorator and you can access the original documentation of 'g'. https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators

Comment: The example above is super simplified, obviously. In my case, f has heaps of logic, might be too much to be placed in a decorator in which we uaually put very thin wrapping code. Additionally, f it is also wrapped, etc, etc. My aim is to have the arg documentation somehow "inherited" up along the wrapping stream.